# How to add a class to an element that is outside of your onclick element

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, onclick

I need some help with some If statement. I have this div

```
<div id="features-dots">
<ul>
    <a href="#"><li class="one"></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="two"></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="three"></li></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="feature_thumb">
<a class="feature_thumb" id="one" onclick="return false;"></a>
</div>
<div class="feature_thumb">
<a class="feature_thumb" id="two" onclick="return false;"></a>
</div>
<div class="feature_thumb">
<a class="feature_thumb" id="three" onclick="return false;"></a>
</div>
```

and want to add a class to li.one if #one is clicked, to li.two if #two is clicked and so on...Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a.feature_thumb').click(function(){
    $('.' + this.id).addClass('your-class');
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lpyghdq/1/)

Comment: How do I add else remove class? So that when .one.your-class is added, others will be removed... Thank you for your help!

Comment: add this first $('.your-class').removeClass('your-class'); and then add this line $('.' + this.id).addClass('your-class');

Answer (score 5):

You can use this simple jQuery code:

```
$('a.feature_thumb').click(function(){
    $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('your-class');
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3Lpyghdq/)

Comment: How do I add else remove class? So that when .one.your-class is added, others will be removed... Thank you for your help! –

Comment: To remove classes, you can use the `.removeClass` method. Like: `element.removeClass('your-class');`. Maybe you want this: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3Lpyghdq/2/